# when i try to connect to mongodb get this error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Here is my NodeJS code

```
const express = require('express'); 
const cors = require('cors'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
require('dotenv').config(); 
const app = express(); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 6000; 
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json()); 

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI; 
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true } ); 

const connection = mongoose.connection; 
connection.once('open', () => { 
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully"); 
}) 

app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`); });
```

This is the `.env` file:

```
ATLAS_URI = mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@cluster0.jnk3w.mongodb.net/xxxxxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

This is the error log

> (node:3812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: option
> usecreateindex is     not supported
> at Object.parseOptions     (D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:281:15)
>
> ```
> at new MongoClient (D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:46)
> at D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:785:16
> at new Promise (<anonymous>)
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:782:19)
> at D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:330:10
> at D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
> at new Promise (<anonymous>)
> at promiseOrCallback (D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
>
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\Front_end\MERN_STACK\Trackerapp\tracker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1151:10)
> ```
>
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:3812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:3812) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

Comment: Can you share the options you are passing the the mongodb version you're using?

Comment: version : "mongoose": "^6.0.2"

Comment: const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 6000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});

Comment: .env file :ATLAS_URI = mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.jnk3w.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: It's very hard to read code from the comments. Please [edit] your question and add the formatted code there

Comment: don't share your db url

Answer (score 1):

Now in version > 6 of mongoose you dont to add
`useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,`
you can simply write
`{mongoose.connect(uri, {});}`

Answer (score 0):

As of version 6.x of mongoose, it is no longer necessary to specify `useNewUrlParser: true` and `useCreateIndex: true`. You can simply leave those options out, your code should work then.

You can read more about it in the mongoose v6.x [migration guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options).